# How can I edit the 'Modified' date field in a sharepoint online list?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, last-modified-date

I thought I'd found a solution to my issue but it seems to only apply to sharepoint on prem. I need to change some content in every document in a library but I want to do so without updating the 'Modified' date field. Ideally I would be able to set the field to not update until I'm done, but if that isn't possible I need a way to set the date for each individual item.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.
Dave

Comment: As `SystemUpdate` and `UpdateOverwriteVersion` are not available in CSOM or in REST what did your on prem-solution do (I guess you didn't use SSOM)?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to do this using [Remote PowerShell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161362%28v=office.15%29.aspx)? It is a long shot, and if you want to use it in practice you would need something like a [remote event receiver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220043%28v=office.15%29.aspx) which triggers a .ps1-script.
But worth a shot/try.

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: I haven't really tried this myself, so you have to follow the links I gave you, and get yourself a big cup of coffee. First things first though, you would have to see if you can get the remote PowerShell to work, and with that change the property. Google for something like "sharepoint 2013 remote powershell" might also help

Answer (score 0):

Modified is a system field.  May I recommend not using it.  Instead create a custom "modified date" field. THIS field you can control.  Use a workflow to set it to the same as the "modified" date or [today].  Then hide the original modified field and expose the "modified date" field.